# QuickLook to preview files in an modal with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to use Quicklook to preview some documents in an app.

There is an array of fileUrls, and i would like to display all the filenames in an UITableView. When the user clicks on an fileName, ill load the selected file.

The problem here is, that the delegate fires automatically when the viewDidLoad, and checks for the selected file, But ill want to push the Quicklook-Controller to my existing UINavigationController.

When ill try with:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    currentFile = TaskFiles[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(preview, animated: false)
}

func numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController(controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func documentsDirectoryURL() -> NSURL {
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let URLs = manager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return URLs[0]
}

func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    return documentsDirectoryURL().URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentFile!.url!)
}
```

It crashes, because the file is (of course) not selected. When ill use an additional viewController, and push the currentFile to the new ViewController, and open the file on ViewDidLoad with:

```
    let preview = QLPreviewController()
    presentViewController(preview, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The Controller is presented fullscreen, but ill prefer to show my file in my existing UINavigationController. Is there a way to accomplish that? Do i need an additional ViewController, or can ill simple push a file to my Quicklookcontroller IN my UINavigationcontroller?

Update:

This is my ViewDidLoad:

```
class ModalFormCaptureFilePreviewViewController: UIViewController,     QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate {

var currentFile:Files?
let preview = QLPreviewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    preview.dataSource = self
    showViewController(preview, sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let preview = QLPreviewController()
showViewController(preview, sender: self)
```

will work, as `presentViewController` uses the `modalPresentationStyle`

**Edited**

This should work

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
    currentFile = TaskFiles[indexPath.row]
    let preview = QLPreviewController()
    preview.dataSource = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(preview, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now its in my NavigationController, but there are still 2 controllers, so when ill click on an UITableViewCell, and the segue gets loaded, ill load my ViewController AND then the QL-Controller gets loaded, so 2 new child controllers (so i need to press 2 times the back button, to go back to my files) - is this the correct usage of the Quicklook-Controller, or can i push it directly from my FilesTableViewController (where ill got the problem with the delegate then)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you are trying to do. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Of Course - i am Atm still in my Cell phone. Which viewdidload do You mean? From my Files Table or from the Filedetail?

Comment: Ok ill updated my Question with the Code from the FileDetailViewController

Comment: I want to see the `viewDidLoad` of your `tableView`, as I don't understand why you said 'The problem here is, delegate fires automatically when the viewDidLoad'

Comment: I dont have the delegate now in my tableView, ill created a new ViewController just to add the QLController. When ill set in my TableViewController "preview.dataSource = self" in ViewDidLoad - it fires when the View loaded (and of course there is no file selected)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94871/discussion-between-zcui93-and-derdida).